# ошибка "отсутсвует список аргументов для шаблон класса"

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Сделал что-то типа хранилища для объектов без использования контейнеров STL , описал методы классов , конструкторы , деструкторы и т.д , но при создании массива объектов c помощью конструктора с параметром в int main выходит ошибка "отсутсвует список аргументов для шаблон класса MyStorage"
Ошибка на 322 строке

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class MyStorage
{
protected:
    int* arr_obj; //указатель на массив
    int size; //размер хранилища
    int capacity; // емкость хранилища
public:
    // КОНСТРУКТОРЫ И ДЕСТРУКТОР
    MyStorage();
    MyStorage(int size);
    ~MyStorage();
    
    void reserve(int capacity); // задать емкость
    
    //ДОБАВЛЕНИЕ ОБЪЕКТОВ
    void push_back(const T& obj);  // добавить в конец
    void push_front(const T& obj); // добавить в начало
    void push_rand(const T& obj);  // добавить в рандомное место 
    void insert(const T& obj, const int& index);//добавить по индексу
    
    //ИЗЪЯТИЕ ОБЪЕКТОВ
    T get_and_delete(int index);   //достать и удалить
    T get(int index);              //достать  
    int find_index(const T& obj);  //достать и вернуть индекс

    //УДАЛЕНИЕ ОБЪЕКТОВ
    void pop_back();       //удалить последний объект
    void pop(int index);   // удалить объект по индексу
    void pop_front();      // удалить первый объект
    
    void clear();  // очистка массива

    int Size();    // вернуть текущий размер массива
    int Capacity();// вернуть максимальный размер массива
    bool is_empty();  //проверка на пустоту массива
    void resize(int size);   //задать новый размер массива


};

template<typename T>
MyStorage<T>::MyStorage() //
{
    arr_obj = nullptr;
    capacity = 0;
    size = 0;
}

template<typename T>
MyStorage<T>::MyStorage(int size) //
{
    arr_obj = new T[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        arr_obj[i] = 0;
    }
    this->size = size;
    capacity = size*2;
}

template <typename T>
void MyStorage<T>::reserve(int capacity)//
{
    if (this->capacity < capacity)
    {
        T* new_arr = new T[capacity];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        {
            new_arr[i] = arr_obj[i];
        }
        delete[] arr_obj;
        arr_obj = new_arr;
        this->capacity = capacity;
    }
}

template <typename T>
void MyStorage<T>::push_back(const T& obj)//
{
    if (size == capacity)
    {
        capacity = size * 2;
        T* new_arr = new T[capacity];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            new_arr[i] = arr_obj[i];
        }
        delete[] arr_obj;
        arr_obj = new_arr;
    }
    size++;
    arr_obj[size] = obj;
}

template <typename T>
void MyStorage<T>::push_front(const T& obj)//
{
    if (size == capacity)
    {
        capacity = size * 2;
        T* new_arr = new T[capacity];
        for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
        {
            new_arr[i] = arr_obj[i];
        }
        delete[] arr_obj;
        arr_obj = new_arr;
    }
    size++;
    arr_obj[0] = obj;
}

template <typename T>
void MyStorage<T>::insert(const T& obj,const int& index)//
{
    capacity = size * 2;
    T* new_arr = new T[capacity];
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
        {
            new_arr[i] = arr_obj[i];
        }
    new_arr[index] = obj;
    for (int i = index + 1; i < size; i++)
        {
            new_arr[i] = arr_obj[i];
        }
    delete[] arr_obj;
    arr_obj = new_arr;
}

template <typename T>
void MyStorage<T>::push_rand(const T& obj)// вроде
{
    int input_obj = rand() % capacity;
    if (input_obj == 0)
    {
        push_front(obj);
    }
    else if (input_obj == size)
    {
        push_back(obj, index);
    }
    else
    {
        insert(obj, input_obj);
    }
}

template<typename T>
T MyStorage<T>::get_and_delete(int index)
{
    if (arr_obj == nullptr || index>size-1)
    {
        return;
    }
    size--;
    capacity = size * 2;
    T* new_arr = new T[capacity];
    get(index);
    if (index == 0)
    {
        pop_front();
    }
    else if (index == size)
    {
        pop_back();
    }
    else
    {
        pop(index);
    }
}

template<typename T>
T MyStorage<T>::get(int index) //
{
    cout << arr_obj[index] << endl;
}

template <typename T>
int MyStorage<T>::find_index(const T& obj)//
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (arr_obj[i] == obj)
        {
            cout << i << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}

template <typename T>
void MyStorage<T>::pop_back()//
{
    if (arr_obj == nullptr)
    {
        return;
    }
    size--;
    T* new_arr = new T[size * 2];
    capacity = size * 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < size-1; i++)
    {
        new_arr[i] = arr_obj[i];
    }
    delete[] arr_obj;
    arr_obj = new_arr;
}

template <typename T>
void MyStorage<T>::pop(int index)//
{
    if (arr_obj == nullptr)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (index == 0)
    {
        pop_front();
    }
    else if (index == size - 1)
    {
        pop_back();
    }
    else
    {
        size--;
        capacity = size * 2;
        T* new_arr = new T[capacity];
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
        {
            new_arr[i] = arr_obj[i];
        }
        for (int i = index; i < size-1; i++)
        {
            new_arr[index] = arr_obj[i + 1];
        }
        delete[] arr_obj;
        arr_obj = new_arr;
    }
}

template <typename T>
void MyStorage<T>::pop_front()//
{
    if (arr_obj == nullptr)
    {
        return;
    }
    size--;
    T* new_arr = new T[size * 2];
    capacity = size * 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        new_arr[i] = arr_obj[i + 1];
    }
    delete[] arr_obj;
    arr_obj = new_arr;
}

template<typename T>
int MyStorage<T>::Size()
{
    return size;
    
}

template <typename T>
int MyStorage<T>::Capacity()
{
    return capacity;
    
}

template <typename T>
bool MyStorage<T>::is_empty()
{
    if (arr_obj == nullptr)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else return 0;
}

template<typename T>
void MyStorage<T>::resize(int size)
{
    if (this->size < size)
    {
        this->size = size;
        T* new_arr = new T[size];
        for (int i = this->size; i<size ; i++)
        {
            new_arr[i] = 0;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            new_arr[i] = arr_obj[i];
        }
    }
    
}

template<typename T>
void MyStorage<T>::clear()
{
    delete[] arr_obj;
}

template<typename T>
MyStorage<T>::~MyStorage() //
{
    delete[] arr_obj;
}
int main()
{
    MyStorage storage(10);



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int* arr_obj;` почему здесь int*, а не T*?

Answer (score 0):

Скажите, в объявлении

```
MyStorage storage(10);
```

как компилятору понять, что вы планируете хранить? `int`, `double`, `string`? Надо указать явно, например:

```
MyStorage<int> storage(10);
```

И тогда останется только одна *синтаксическая* ошибка — в строке

```
    push_back(obj, index);
```

в `push_rand()` используется нигде не объявленная переменная `index`.

О *семантических* ошибках не говорю ничего, это вы сами...

Comment: а как инициализировать хранилище объектов без конкретного типа ?

Comment: просто по заданию требуется, что бы хранилище было предусмотрено для хранения любых объектов

Comment: Хранилище и предусмотрено (в той мере, в которой вы его верно написали) для хранения объектов разных типов — но в одном хранилище хранятся объекты только одного типа. Который и надо указать. Вас же не удивляет, что вы пишете `vector<int>`, например?